# When will OpenGL ES 3.1 be supported in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.1

The OpenGL ES 3.1 specification was released on [March 17th, 2014.](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-opengl-es-3.1-specification)

Does anybody know if there is a timetable for adding it to the Android SDK?

Comment: There may be a timetable, but if there is one, it will be internal to Google. They do not generally make statements about future API support, until the future becomes the present and such support ships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles on this and is curious. OpenGL ES 3.1 is supported in Android now, as of Android 5.0 (API 21). The device's hardware still has to support it, though.

See the `Graphics` section of [The official Google 5.0 API info](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Graphics)

Comment: So far it seems only the nexus 6 and nvidia shield support it

Answer (score 3):

Intel showed OpenGL ES 3.1 on GDC on Android x64 on Bay Trail.

Catch though is that Android x64 is developed by Intel, so Google may have its own timetable for implementing OpenGL ES 3.1 or even may skip it in favor for full OpenGL 4.x (Since both Qualcom and Nvidia, and some others seam to implement such features in hw).